# Symfony - (1/1) InvalidConfigurationException - Unrecognized option "mailer" under "framework"

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks, mailer

I'm quite new at Symfony and struggle with this issue for my internship, when trying to run the project locally :

```
(1/1) InvalidConfigurationException        
 In ArrayNode.php line 331:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      Unrecognized option "mailer" under "framework". Available options are "annotations", "assets", "cache", [...], "workflows".
```

I'm running PHP 7.4 and Symfony 4, adapting a symfony project from another dev.

In my .env file, I got swiftmailer bundle, I believe mailer was a different kind of mailer bundle used..?

I tried the following request :

```
 composer require symfony/mailer
```

And got this :

```
    The "symfony/flex" plugin was skipped because it is not compatible with Composer 2+. Make sure to update it to version 1.9.8 or greater.
Using version ^5.2 for symfony/mailer
./composer.json has been updated
The "symfony/flex" plugin was skipped because it is not compatible with Composer 2+. Make sure to update it to version 1.9.8 or greater.
Running composer update symfony/mailer
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - symfony/mailer[v5.2.0, ..., v5.2.2] require symfony/event-dispatcher ^4.4|^5.0 -> found symfony/event-dispatcher[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.19, v5.0.0, ..., v5.2.2] but the package is fixed to v4.2.8 (lock file version) by a partial up
date and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/mailer ^5.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/mailer[v5.2.0, v5.2.1, v5.2.2].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're kickstarting another dev's project, you probably don't need any `composer require`. All you have to do is run `composer install` in project directory to get all the same packages, as previous developer.

Comment: I tried to run composer install but it failed. I was adviced then to run a composer update and it failed too (couldn't download some files from packagist.org (HHTP/2 504)

Comment: @Jerome59 Can you provide an output of command?

Comment: Result of the composer install: https://codeshare.io/G8RBzE

Comment: Have you tried running `composer update`, as this log suggests?

Comment: HI, yes I tried and I faced errors too. I restarted again from a clean project and built the vendors thanks to composer install as you suggest, and it finally worked! As I didn't proceed that way the first time.